# Java - Pass class as argument and use it to call a function

Tags: java

is there a way of getting a class as argument and then from that class variable call a function?
(I don't know the class name, but i know the function name)

```
public void executeFunction(RandomClass class1){
    class1.sayHi();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use the reflection API (unnecessarily)?

Comment: You mean you don't know `RandomClass`? Then declare the argument with type `Object` and use reflection to call the method.

Comment: You either are looking for reflection, or simple common type which all instances will need to extend/implement.

Comment: I'll tak a look at it.

Comment: You could also try "passing the function in" - using a functional interface.  Wouldn't require reflection, although would require Java 8

Comment: This question is usually [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you post example of how do you plan to use this method? Do you know methods name when you write your code? Or will it be decided at runtime?

Comment: The only kind of function you call on a "class" is static method. Regular methods are called on **instances** of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to do this. Example:

```
public void executeFunction(Class class1) throws Exception{
        for(Method m : class1.getMethods()){
            if(m.getName().equals("sayHi"))
            m.invoke(class1.getConstructor().newInstance());
            //default constructor used to get a object of the class
            //if there is not default constructor this will fail
        }
    }
```